# Very quiet and buzzy sound in headphones on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, update-manager, headphones

It's very quiet and buzzy sound in headphones on my Ubuntu 16.04. I experienced this issue about a month ago and I tried to fix that with "pavucontrol" and "alsamixer" utils, but these didn't help. Suddenly system update with standard "System Update" manager helped me. But now it doesn't. Strange thing that built-in dynamics works correctly. Please help, guys... Just don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that was but simple "Suspend" helped me :)